# How to submit form after success ajax post?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

When i load page `index.php` , and click link `DELETE` , it's will be post value to `demo.php`

and in `demo.php` after update data into `table product` why not auto submit form `id="myForm"`
.

.

index.php

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function delete_pro_fn() {
    $('#mySpan').hide();
    $('#loading').show();
        $.ajax
        (
            {
                url: 'demo.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#fid1').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#loading').hide();
                    $('#mySpan').show();
                    $('#mySpan').html(data);
                }
            }
        )
}
</script>

<form id="fid1" method="post" action="" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data" style=" display: none; ">
    <input type="text" name="id_delete" value="1234567890"/>
</form>

<a href="JavaScript:delete_pro_fn()">DELETE</a>
<div id="loading" style="display: none;">Loading..........................</div>
<div id="mySpan"></div>
```

demo.php

```
<?PHP
include("connect.php");
$sql = "UPDATE product SET delete = '1' WHERE id = '$_POST[id_delete]'";
$dbQuery = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="products.php" method="POST">
    <input name="delete" value="1" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
  document.forms['myForm'].submit()
}
</script>
```

Comment: why can't you just delete the record in `demo.php`.. why do you want to sent a request to another url

Comment: the problem is you are using `window.onload` which will be fired only once when the page is loaded... since the snippet is loaded via ajax most probably the window load event would have occurred... so the handler will not get called

Comment: – @ Arun P Johny could you please give me some code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To submit the form after the ajax post, just:

```
$('#myForm').submit();
```

edit complete function:

```
function delete_pro_fn() {
    $('#mySpan').hide();
    $('#loading').show();
        $.ajax
        (
            {
                url: 'demo.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#fid1').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#loading').hide();
                    $('#mySpan').show();
                    $('#mySpan').html(data);
 $('#myForm').submit();
                }
            }
        )
}
</script>
```

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#myForm').submit();
    </script>`

not work .

Comment: write this line inside de success event